# Dynamically generate <tr> through a function in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following function that is supposed to return a `<tr>` when we map over the elements:

```
renderProductRow = () => {
    let table;
        for(let product in this.props.productProgressInfo){
            productName.push(this.props.productProgressInfo[product]);
        }
//productName is an array that simply holds the name of the products
        productName.map((name:any)=> {
            table = <tr>
                        <td>Product</td>
                        <td>{name}</td>
                        <td>{this.props.siteStatusQueued}</td>
                    </tr>
            return table;
        })
      return table;
    }
  return table;
}
```

In my `render()` return statement I am calling `this.renderProductRow()`. When it fires, I can see 1 row getting rendered for a split second and then disappearing. My guess is I'm somehow messing up the return statement in the function.

Comment: It also looks like you have one too many `return table; }` at the end of your code.

Comment: You might consider rolling back your edit to the prior state (rather than updating as you solved the problem.  It makes the question answer pair easier to understand for those who might come across this in the future with a similar problem or wanting to add to the discussion... but you might also add an addendum asking how best to implement the conditional since that only comes up in the comments below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `map`, which you'd like to return, is an array, but you're not storing the result.  Using `table` as variable is confusing because after your map function exits, it stays set to the value produced by the last entry in productName.

It looks like you mean to do this:

```
renderProductRow = () => {

  if (<condition>) {

    for(let product in this.props.productProgressInfo){
        productName.push(this.props.productProgressInfo[product]);
    }

   return  productName.map((name:any)=> {
        return (<tr>
                    <td>Product</td>
                    <td>{name}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.siteStatusQueued}</td>
                </tr>)
    }) }
   else
   {return null}  // or return an empty array [] depending on what parent component expects.
}
```

Comment: Aha making sense now. What should I do if I have an if statement wrapping around both the for loop and the map function? I've updated the original post to show what I mean.

Comment: `null` is a valid return type in react.  So you can do `if (condition) return x else return null`.  Updating above...

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!